# Where's documented combo box usage with zenity?

Tags: zenity

I found by chance it was possible to display a combo box with zenity (version tested: 2.32.1). See the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(a b c d e)
value=$(zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text "${array[@]}" --text "Insert your choice.")
```

The result is illustrated with the following 3 images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have two questions about that:

1. Is there a documentation about this functionality? I didn't find anything in the [zenity documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/2.32/zenity.html).
2. Why the first value of my array doesn't appear in the combo box? In the example above, my array is `(a b c d e)`, and the combo box only displays `b c d e`.

   As a workaround, I add a value in my array, for example `(0 a b c d e)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first element of the array gets eaten up by `--text`. After expansion, your zenitiy line looks like:

```sh
zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text a b c d e --text "Insert your choice."
# Which zenity treats equivalent to
zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text a --text "Insert your choice." b c d e
```

So you first set the text to `a`, then you override that with "Insert your choice." And the remaining arguments become the choices.

What you want is:

```sh
zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text "Insert your choice." a b c d e
# Hence:
zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text "Insert your choice." "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 8):

This is actually documented (maybe not at the time the question was posted, didn't check), not in the manual but in `zenity --help-forms` :

```
$ LANG=en_US zenity --help-forms
Usage:
  zenity [OPTION...]

Forms dialog options
  --forms                                           Display forms dialog
  --add-entry=Field name                            Add a new Entry in forms dialog
  --add-password=Field name                         Add a new Password Entry in forms dialog
  --add-calendar=Calendar field name                Add a new Calendar in forms dialog
  --add-list=List field and header name             Add a new List in forms dialog
  --list-values=List of values separated by |       List of values for List
  --column-values=List of values separated by |     List of values for columns
  --add-combo=Combo box field name                  Add a new combo box in forms dialog
  --combo-values=List of values separated by |      List of values for combo box
  --show-header                                     Show the columns header
  --text=TEXT                                       Set the dialog text
  --separator=SEPARATOR                             Set output separator character
  --forms-date-format=PATTERN                       Set the format for the returned date
```

Therefore:

```sh
zenity --forms --title "Window title" --text "Combo name" --add-combo "Insert your choice." --combo-values "a|b|c|d|e"
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `--text-entry` for the array of values, not `--text` ([reference](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/2.32/zenity.html#zenity-text-entry-options)).  Using:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
array=(a b c d e)
value=$(zenity --entry --title "Window title" --entry-text "${array[@]}" --text "Insert your choice.")
```

I see the default value of the dropdown box pre-filled with the first value of array, and all values available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's curious that the manual does not refer to combo box.